# option_value is empty when i'm submitting the form - Wordpress custom settings page

Tags: php, database, wordpress, plugins, optionmenu

The context is as follows: We are on WAMPSERVER so locally. I want to create an options page for my own plugin. I followed several tutorials and I created this small and simple test:
[The settings page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aO8RD.png)

For the moment, everything is fine.
But here is the problem, in the 'wp_options' table in the Wordpress database, I see my variable but the 'option_value' column is empty after my submit.
Example : In my field I put 'test_value', I press the submit button, I should see it in the 'option_value' column of 'my_var'.

But here is the result of my submit on my database in phpMyAdmin :
[the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqjUN.png)

Here is the code for this test:

```php
add_action('admin_init', 'register_fields_opac');
function register_fields_opac() {
    register_setting('var_id', 'my_var', 'sanitize_text_field');
    add_settings_section('section_id', '', '', 'the_option_page_slug');
    add_settings_field('field_id', 'field_name', 'var_test', 'the_option_page_slug', 'section_id');
}

function var_test() {
    $test = get_option('field_id');
    
    printf( 
        '<input type="text" id="field_id" size="75" value="%s"/>'
        , $test    
    );
}


function display_options() {
    echo '<div class="wrap">
        <h1> Test </h1>

        <form action="options.php" method="post">';
        
    settings_fields('var_id');
    
    do_settings_sections('the_option_page_slug');
    
    echo '<input type="submit"/>';
    
    echo '</form></div>';
}
```

What is the problem? Can we also change the 'autoload' variable with a function similar to 'register_settings' instead of 'update_option'?

Information about me:
I'm a beginner on Wordpress (and stackOverflow), this is my first assignment on a CMS. If you need more information, don't hesitate to tell me.

1. PHP version : 7.4.9
2. Wordpress : 5.8.2 french version
3. MySQL version : 5.7.31
4. PhpMyAdmin : 5.0.2

Comment: is the name value of the input == my_var ?

Comment: my_var is the option name, the name of the input doesn't have name, but an id 'field_id'. But, the field in the option which is in the 'register_fields_opac' function, has a name which is 'field_name'. This is a way to get it with get_option.